# Is there an easy way to convert a vector int set to a string output?

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to jump into code again and doing what I can to teach myself the ins and outs of C++. I have the following code that I have been studying and needed to adapt it to a project where I find the factorial decomposition of a number.

The code seems to work and I can output it to the console but I want to process it into a string variable and return that but the main issue I have is converting it from a vector (int , int) to a std::string variable.

I've tried adding the variables and casting them to the string but everytime I do, I seem to lose data.

```
    struct factor {
        long prime;
        long power;
    };

    std::string decomp(int n) {
        std::vector<factor> result;
        for (long i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
            auto prime = true;
            for (auto &f : result) {
                for (auto r = i; r % f.prime == 0; r /= f.prime) {
                    prime = false;
                    ++f.power;
                }
            }
            if (prime) {
                result.push_back({ i, 1 });
            }
        }

for (auto& f : result)
{
    std::cout << f.prime;
    if (f.power > 1) {
        std::cout << "^" << f.power;
    }
    std::cout << " ";
}
```

}

I have it formatted where the first is the prime number and the second is the power of that prime. I want it to display say, (3, 7) as 3^7 in my string with a space between all new primes such as 3^7 5^3 etc....

Comment: Are you familiar with [std::stringstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream)?

Answer (score 0):

Like *Bob__* said, you can use [`std::stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) and use it as a drop-in replacement for `std::cout`.

```
#include <sstream>

std::string to_string(std::vector<factor> const& decomp) 
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    for (auto const& f : decomp)
    {
        ss << f.prime;
        if (f.power > 1) 
            ss << '^' << f.power;
        ss << ' ';
    }
    return ss.str();
}
```

As a side note: I suggest you split the decomposition and string conversion in two seperate functions: